# Can you coppice a pear tree?

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, technique, pear

I've heard of coppicing apple trees, but if you coppice a pear tree, will it grow back (and does the variety matter)? This is with regard to standard-sized pear trees (without a different rootstock). I'm not talking about pollarding (although that would be interesting to know, too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not healthy, but I've seen it be successful (pollarding also) on fireblight infested pear trees, so long as you cut above the graft (most trees, not yours). Otherwise you get rootstock fruit. keep in mind that this isn't always successful and may kill the tree. It is best performed in early spring.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the information. We actually have a pear tree full of fire blight right now. So, that's a nice coincidence (although it's not the full reason I asked the question).